# Organising Folder with same file names and creating a subfolder for them

Tags: python, glob, python-re

I have a folder full of tiktok videos I have downloaded. The filenames look like this "2022-12-25_@sample123_7181201932356120774" I want to create a folder for each creator that has more than 1 video. In this case it would be for "sample123"

Here is the code I produced so far, i have a list of the filenames in the folder and managed to split it down to just the creators @

```
import glob
import os.path

# fle name template is "2022-12-25_@sample123_7181201932356120774"

dir = 'C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\sample test'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.mp4'))

for file in files:
    a = file.split("@")[1]
    b = a.split("_")[0]
    print(b) # output is sample123
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: You could create a dictionary `{creator: [filename1, filename 2...], ...}`, then move the files for all (key, value) pairs where len(value) > 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary with this structure: {creator: [filename1, filename 2...], ...}, then move the files for all (key, value) pairs where len(value) > 1. Here's some code for that:

```
import glob
import os.path
from os import makedirs, rename

# fle name template is "2022-12-25_@sample123_7181201932356120774"

my_dir = 'C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\sample test'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(my_dir, '*.mp4'))

creator_dic = {}

for file in files:
    a = file.split("@")[1]
    b = a.split("_")[0]
    #print(b) # output is sample123
    creator_dic.setdefault(b, []).append(file)

for creator, filelist in creator_dic.items():
    if len(filelist) > 1:
        creator_folder = f'{my_dir}/{creator}/'
        makedirs(creator_folder, exist_ok=True)
        for file in filelist:
            file = file.split('\\')[-1]
            rename(f'{my_dir}/{file}', f'{creator_folder}{file}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, It all makes sense but I get a syntax error for the very last line of code.  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\sample test/C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\sample test\\2022-07-25_@sample123_7124375743894736171.mp4' -> 'C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\sample test/sample123/C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\sample test\\2022-07-25_@sample123_7124375743894736171.mp4'

Comment: Yes, I'm used to `listdir`, that only gives the bare filename; I added the `file = file.split('\\')[-1]` line to prevent the problem you mentioned; perhaps you copied my code before I fixed that.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, honestly you are a God send

Comment: Any files in the specified directory with the .mp4 suffix but without @ in the filename will induce an IndexError exception. Why are you renaming the files? The requirement is "...to create a folder for each creator..."

Comment: Oh you're right; I was convinced the files had to be moved o it, but it's actually not specified in the question. My imagination strikes again :)

Comment: @Swifty You will also find that you can easily resolve your somewhat mixed usage of directory separators with judicious use of the pathlib module. See my answer for an example

Comment: I always use '/' ; the mixing comes from my deciding not to change the original code (except renaming `dir` of course). But I'm aware it's ugly ;)

Answer (score 1):

The *pathlib* module is ideal for this as it has its own *glob* functionality.

Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
from re import findall

SOURCE_DIR = Path('C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\sample test')

creators = {}

for file in SOURCE_DIR.glob('*.mp4'):
    try:
        creator, *_ = findall(r'@(.*)_', file.name)
        creators[creator] = creators.get(creator, 0) + 1
    except ValueError:
        ...

for k, v in creators.items():
    if v > 1:
        Path(SOURCE_DIR / k).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use a dictionary (named `buckets`) to keep track of users and their list of files. For those user with more than 1 file:

1. Create a sub directory with that user's name
2. Move that user's files to the new directory

```py
import collections
import pathlib

data_dir = pathlib.Path(r"C:\Users\name\Downloads\sample test")

# Use a dictionary to keep track of users and their files list
# Buckets is a dict of {user: [list of files]}
buckets = collections.defaultdict(list)
for path in data_dir.glob("*.mp4"):
    _, *user, _ = path.name.split("_")
    user = "_".join(user)
    buckets[user].append(path)

# For those users with more than 1 files, mkdir a sub dir
# and move that user's files
for user, paths in buckets.items():
    # Skip those users with only 1 file
    if len(paths) == 1:
        continue

    # Create a separate directory for a user
    dest_dir = data_dir / user
    dest_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    # Move files
    for path in paths:
        path.rename(dest_dir / path.name)
```

#### Notes

- I use `pathlib` instead of `os.path` because the former is nicer to work with. For example,  if `data_dir` is "C:\Users\name\Downloads\sample test" and `user` is '@sample123', then `data_dir / user` will become "C:\Users\name\Downloads\sample test@sample123"
- I use `collections.defaultdict` to simplify putting file names into buckets
- when calling `mkdir`, I passing the named argument of `exist_ok=True` so that if the directory already exists, I don't get an exepction.

#### Update

I see the problem you are facing: Some user has embedded underscore in their names. In order to address this, I would like to propose the following change:

```
    _, *user, _ = path.name.split("_")
    user = "_".join(user)
```

The first line will split on underscore, but ends up with user being a list. For example, given the filename "2017-02-03_@johnny_goode_123413414", then `user` will be `["@johnny", "goode"]`

The next line reconstruct the user name by joining the pieces together using the underscore.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I get this error message any idea why?  _, user, _ = path.name.split("_")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: That is because your file name does not follow the pattern `<data>_@user_suffix`. I guess some of your file has less than 2 underscores in its name. Let me think of some work-around.

Comment: Please see my update. I use `contextlib.suppress()` to ignore the `ValueError`. You might want to print out those names which causes trouble and post and update so that I and others can work out a plan to deal with them.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you so much for everything.

Comment: I've just noticed that it ignored all the creators that have an _ in their name, any work around?

Comment: A simple way to adress the 'creator with underscore' problem could be to use re: `re.findall(r'@(.*)_', path.name)[0]` should return the full username (thanks to the greediness of *).

Comment: The new code gives this error, any idea why _, *user, _ = path.name.split("_")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 1)

Comment: Hello @Tab, please update your question with those names that are troublesome. Otherwise, I am just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: An example is @funny_meme013, thank you for the help

Comment: What are the full file names?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pathlib`, a regular expression and `collections.defaultdict`. My example is using a generator function `extract` for the name extraction and file filtering.

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict

from typing import Generator, Tuple
```

```py
def extract(
    regex_pattern: str,
    folder: Path, 
    group: int = 0,  # 0 = full file name without extension
    glob_pattern: str = "*",
    recursive: bool = False) -> Generator[Tuple[str, Path], None, None]:

    glob_pattern = f"**/{glob_pattern}" if recursive else glob_pattern

    for path in folder.glob(glob_pattern):

        if path.is_dir():
            continue
        
        result = re.match(regex_pattern, path.name)
        if result:
            if group == 0:
                yield path.stem, path
            else:
                yield result.group(group), path
```

```py
FOLDER = Path("/home/name/playground")

creators = defaultdict(list)

for name, file in extract(r"(.*)@(.*)_(.*)", FOLDER, 2):
    creators[name].append(file)

for creator, videos in creators.items():
    if len(videos) > 1:
        Path(FOLDER / creator).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        for video in videos:
            video.rename(FOLDER / creator / video.name)
```

---

**Side note:** I use this generator to move shapefiles to specific folders. Shapefiles have different file extensions but the same stem.

```py
FOLDER = Path("/home/name/data")

for name, file in extract(r"(.*?)\d*[.].*", FOLDER, 1, recursive=True):

    Path(FOLDER / name).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    file.rename(FOLDER / name / file.name)
```

Here is an example input:

[image]

The script moves the input to:

```
BuildingPermits
-- BuildingPermits2004.shp
-- BuildingPermits2004.dbf
-- ...
-- BuildingPermits2005.shp
-- BuildingPermits2005.dbf
-- ...
-- BuildingPermits.shp
-- BuildingPermits.dbf
-- ...
...
```